# Class 'app\assets\AppAsset' not found issue in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, composer-php

I've just installed yii2 basic project via composer and ran `composer install` and `composer update` . But I get the following error as it tries to open `main.php` default layout page. the error says it cannot find the AppAsset class. How can I fix the issue ?
this is the error:

```
Class 'app\assets\AppAsset' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because of my gitignore file, I have put the asset directory in to the gitignore file by accident and because of that, when I git cloned from the project some classes were not found.

Answer (score 3):

By default, when you install yii2, a file `AppAsset.php` will be created at: `/path-to-application/assets/AppAssset.php`.

If, for some reason, it didn't, I would strongly recommend reinstall the framework, just in case of anything else is missing. Be sure you are following the [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

IF you just need this file, you can find its content here in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html):

```
<?php

namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Comment: The project doesn't have any problem of missing files in the server, but when I clone it from git at home, this file is missing and I cannot open the default project. how can I fix this issue after cloning ?

Comment: So.. you didn't "just installed yii2 basic project via composer" like you said, but cloned from elsewhere. Sorry I didn't help you properly, but try to be more clear next time :P